# In Romans 1:17, what does Paul mean by “from faith to faith” (ἐκ πίστεως εἰς πίστιν)?

Tags: romans, law, faith

> <sup>17</sup> For in it the righteousness of God is revealed **from faith to faith**; as it is written, “But the righteous man shall live by faith.” <sup>NASB, ©1995</sup>
>
> <sup>ΙΖʹ</sup> δικαιοσύνη γὰρ θεοῦ ἐν αὐτῷ ἀποκαλύπτεται **ἐκ πίστεως εἰς πίστιν**, καθὼς γέγραπται· ὁ δὲ δίκαιος ἐκ πίστεως ζήσεται. <sup>NA28, ©2012</sup>

When I read “from faith to faith,” I thought it was a temporal statement (i.e. from law to grace—the faith once delivered). But I have read three commentaries on Romans (not just for this question but just in general because it is my favorite epistle), and no one so far has mentioned that it is a temporal statement. Am I totally off the mark? Could there be no transitional temporal meaning to the phrase “from faith to faith?”

Comment: True faith was always a requirement even under the Law which was the true faith of its time.  The Jews were warned not to believe in their own righteousness even in the Old Covenant. Which is why I believe Paul quotes Hab 2:4

Comment: I think it's a Greek Idiom which does not communicate at all when translated literally like that into English.

Comment: @curiousdannii If you know of such an idiom, I'd be curious. AFAIK it's not been terribly clear to anybody what it means. The only NT parallel (again AFAIK) is also Pauline, 2 Cor. 2:16: οἷς μὲν ὀσμὴ ἐκ θανάτου εἰς θάνατον, οἷς δὲ ὀσμὴ ἐκ ζωῆς εἰς ζωήν ("to those a fragrance from death to death, to the others a fragrance from life to life.'").

Comment: @Susan There's also 'hope upon hope' in Rom 4. Maybe it's more of a favourite Pauline structure than an idiom.

Comment: @curiousdannii Two different prepositions + cases (παρ᾿ ἐλπίδα ἐπ᾿ ἐλπίδι vs. ἐκ [gen] εἰς [acc]). (But agreed that he likes to repeat words for rhetorical purposes!)

Comment: Are you asking if it is "from a time of faith to another time of faith"? If so, no, that isn't the point. He labors hard to show that the law is not of faith but rather of works (or at least "faith plus works" which at the end of the day is simply "by works". The temporal thing doesn't work.

Comment: @Susan I know this is an old discussion but you might be interested in the work of Terry Wardlaw on this subject. I know nothing about the author but found his work instructive (but challenging, as it is quite scholarly and academic).  https://biblicalstudies.org.uk/pdf/ejt/21-2_107.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what commentaries you looked at. But you're in good company with **Calvin**, who seems to indicate a clear *temporal sense* in the phrase "from faith unto faith":

> The more our knowledge of true religion increases, we see the grace of God with greater clarity and more familiarity, as though He were coming nearer to us. ... [This phrase] marks the daily progress of every believer.<sup>1</sup>

**Charles Hodge** interprets it more as *an intensification* of "by faith"  (but notice his rather tentative "*may* mean"):

> As "death unto death" and "life unto life" are intensive, so "faith unto faith" may mean, entirely of faith.<sup>2</sup>

**Haldane** is of a different opinion, that the meaning is neither temporal nor emphatic (primarily), but an *elliptical* statement, that is, missing some words which could've been repeated but weren't, which when inserted yield a clear meaning (highlighted below). He also presents a nice catalog of others' interpretations:

> Some explain it as signifying from the faith of the Old Testament to the faith of the New; some, from one degree of faith to another; some, from the faith of the Jew to the faith of the Gentile; and others, altogether of faith. The expression is evidently elliptical; and in order to understand it, it is necessary to observe that the literal rendering is not ‘from faith to faith,’ but ‘by faith to faith.’ The same words in the original are thus translated in the same verse: ‘The just shall live by faith.’ **The meaning, then, is, the righteousness which is by faith, namely, which is received by faith, is revealed to faith, or in order to be believed.** This is entirely constant with what the Apostle says in ch. 3:22, where he reverts to the subject, and announces that the righteousness of God, which is by, or through, faith of Jesus Christ, is unto all and upon all them that believe.<sup>3</sup>

I don't think Haldane is totally rejecting the temporal sense. You are free to interpret the verse both ways, as the Spirit leads.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> John Calvin, *The Epistles of Romans and Thessalonians*, 1539, trans. Ross Mackenzie in 1884, (Grand Rapids: Eerdmans), p.28.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Charles Hodge, *Commentary on the Epistle to the Romans*, 1886, (Ann Arbor: Cushing-Malloy, 1953), p.32.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> Robt. Haldane, *Exposition of the Epistle to the Romans*, 1874, (Edinburgh: Banner of Truth, 1958), p.49.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

|  | Subject Phrase | Predicate Phrase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Main Assertion | δικαιοσύνη γὰρ θεοῦ | ἐν αὐτῷ ἀποκαλύπτεται |
| Prepositional Modifier | ἐκ πίστεως | εἰς πίστιν |
| Translation | For a righteousness from God [that is] by faith | is revealed in [the Gospel] for faith |

The idea is that the righteousness from God is obtained by faith, while the message revealed in the Gospel is productive of faith.

Cf. Romans 10:17

> Faith comes from hearing the message, and the message is heard through the word of Christ. [NIV-84]

Comment: Hi William, welcome to the site. I updated the table formatting--it just needed colons and the removal of some unnecessary spaces. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour), and thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

To me, the Epistle to the Romans is a job application, albeit an unsolicited one. Paul spends the first chapter winning the trust  of the Romans, assuring them that he would fit into their group. Paul begins with a lengthy opening address no doubt designed to impress the Roman Christians that he was, at the same time, sincere and unassuming, and that his teachings about Jesus Christ were in accordance with their own. Paul hopes to preach in Rome for a while (1:15), and needs their acceptance. Romans chapter 15 is an assurance that the stopover will be brief and that he does not intend to step on any toes, before proceeding to Spain. In this regard:

> Romans 15:14: And I myself also am persuaded of you, my brethren, that ye also are full of goodness, filled with all knowledge, able also to admonish one another.

In this context, what follows should not be interpreted as Paul writing something to the Romans that they did not already know. Although he had never met the Christians of Rome, he knew they already had faith in Jesus and already believed the gospel. He wanted to show them that he was on the same page.

In verse 16, Paul says he is not ashamed to proclaim the gospel, which he tells the Romans is the power of God for the salvation of everyone who believes: Jew first, and then Greek (Gentile). Verse 1:17 then echoes  Habakkuk 2:4 (and possibly Psalm 98), concluding with the citation from Habakkuk 2:4, in Romans 1:17b:

> Romans 1:17b: as it is written, The just shall live by faith.

[Matthew Poole](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/poole/romans/1.htm) says this apostle seems to delight in repetitions such as as 'from faith to faith', and there is an elegancy in them.  He says the words are variously interpreted and gives two examples:

- from the faith of the Old Testament to the faith of the New
- from a lesser faith to a greater; not noting two faiths, but one and the same faith increasing to perfection.

To extrapolate from Poole's commentary, some theologians are merely speculating as to the meaning of this phrase, seeking to find in it something that suits their own theology.

Steve Moyise makes a reasonable point in 'Quotations', published in *[As It Is Written](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/As_it_is_Written.html?id=FwxqQacv9b4C&redir_esc=y)*, page 21, that it is extremely unlikely that Paul first formulated his gospel as the revelation of God's righteousness 'of' or 'from' faith and only later discovered that Hab 2:4 is the only text in the whole of scripture to make such a connection. It is much more likely that Paul began with the Habakkuk text and formulated his doctrine accordingly.

That being the case we can say that, to a significant extent, Paul's message is defined not by Habakkuk's message, but by Habakkuk's words,  which Paul paraphrases but can only change so much. And because Paul did not start from an an intended statement that he found Habakkuk supported, but started from Habakkuk, we should not read too much into how he used words, but keep our focus on the broader message.

Moyise (*ibid*, page 18) says that, since Paul is introducing himself to the Roman church, he cites a text that he knows (or thinks he knows) will be common ground, and in this way he will gain their confidence. He has deftly altered the meaning of Habakkuk's words and mingled his own words with those of Habakkuk in order to give the impression that Habakkuk means what Paul means.

The precise meaning, as intended by Paul, of "from faith to faith" is obscure, and perhaps that is how Paul intended to leave it. If Matthew Poole is correct when he says Paul delighted in repetitions like this one, then Paul was using this particular construct because it delighted him.  More broadly, he wanted to talk about faith, and he wanted to demonstrate that his teachings were well grounded in scripture by citing a passage that would resonate with the Romans.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the phrase "from faith to faith" may well be transitional in quite another sense. Can I first refer to Romans 3:21,22 where Paul talks about God's righteousness being revealed [in the gospel] which is "given through faith in Jesus Christ to all who believe" [NIV] with footnotes suggesting an alternative: "through the faithfulness of Jesus". Here, sadly our English vocabulary lets us down - faith = Greek pistis; believe = Greek pisteuo the endings being the difference between the noun and the verb. So the NIV has Paul saying "through (a person's) faith (in Jesus) to all who have faith (in Jesus)" - I think not! - the alternative is clearly the better - "through the faithfulness of Jesus to all who are faithful (to Jesus)". Here, I think is the transition - our faithfulness is a response to His.

Having made the first "faith" of Rom. 1:17 that of Jesus, I need to address the question: 'in what sense is Jesus (and are we to be) faithful?'. In 1:17 "from faith to faith" is in reference to the righteousness of God revealed in the gospel. NT Wright suggests that God's righteousness is His unswerving commitment to uphold His covenant with His people and indeed with His creation (to honour His word). So in Rom. 1:17 the gospel reveals God's righteousness in that He finally moves to make the covenant work - not only from His side [which it has always done] but from humanity's, by doing for us what we couldn't do for ourselves - uphold the covenant - which is what faithful Jesus has done. We, on our part, can partake of that covenant faithfulness of Jesus by being faithful to Him - declaring our allegiance to Him as King [Messiah (Hebrew) = Christ (Greek) = God's anointed king] and hence our representative [and substitute].

Comment: This answer has English composition problems. It is unstructured and hard to follow. Please try to re-write it in three or maybe four separate short paragraphs, each with a leading sentence and two or three supporting sentences that express one idea per paragraph. There should be a logical sequence to the paragraphs leading to a final summary paragraph that clearly answers the OP's question. It is not clear to me in what sense you are using the word "transitional". Transitional from what to what?

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments. I have created a second paragraph to distinguish the transition issue from an explanation of "faithfulness" and then restructured the second paragraph to make a better fist of that explanation.

Answer (score 1):

### In Romans 1:17, what does Paul mean by “from faith to faith” (ἐκ πίστεως εἰς πίστιν)?

**Romans 1:16-17 (ESV)**

> 16 For I am not ashamed of the gospel, for it is the power of God for salvation to everyone who believes, to the Jew first and also to the Greek. 17 For in it the righteousness of God is revealed **from faith for faith,** as it is written, “The righteous shall live by faith.”

**In context, Romans 1:16-17 is all about the Gospel:**

1. The Gospel Paul is not ashamed of
2. The Gospel that is the power of God for salvation
3. The Gospel that is for everyone who believes
4. The Gospel within which the righteousness of God is revealed.

So when Paul says in verse 17 that *"in it (the Gospel) the righteousness of God is revealed **from faith for faith,**”* he is continuing to talk about the Gospel - the Gospel of which Paul himself has been set apart (v1). The Gospel is the frame of reference we should keep in mind when trying to meaning of *"from faith for faith."*

In the *Enhanced Strong's Dictionary,* the entry for the word translated as **faith** reads as folows:

> **g4102.** ***πίστις pistis;*** from **3982**; persuasion, i.e. credence; moral conviction (of religious truth, or the truthfulness of God or a religious teacher), especially reliance upon Christ for salvation; abstractly, constancy in such profession; **by extension, the system of religious (Gospel) truth itself:** — assurance, belief, believe, faith, fidelity.

So, it turns out that *pistis* may refer to the faith that a person has but also it may refer to the very truth that the person is supposed to have faith in - thus the word faith can function as a stand-in both for one's belief in the Gospel and for the very Gospel itself. This is how I understand how Paul is using the word faith in the phrase "from faith for faith".
Thus Romans 1:17 can be translated as follows:

> For in it, *the Gospel,* the righteousness of God is revealed - from faith, *the system of belief that is the Gospel,* for *a person's* faith *in that same system of belief - the Gospel -* for the righteous shall live by *their* faith *in the Gospel*, as it is written, “The righteous shall live by faith” ( - their faith in the Gospel).*

The righteousness that was formerly concealed has now been revealed to us from the Gospel, the Faith - the system of belief we have received. This righteousness, which has been revealed in the Gospel, provides for us the substance of belief empowering those who believe to obtain the salvation of God through their faith in The Faith, The Gospel, and thus live.

---

**Note:** While true that the quote, "The righteous shall live by faith” is and Old Testament quote, Paul is clearly purposing it in relation to the Gospel he has been set apart for.  Furthermore, Paul believed that the Gospel was proclaimed to the Old Testament saints back at least since the time of Abraham (Gal 3:8) though, of course, the fullness of the Gospel was yet only to be revealed in the person of Jesus Christ.

Comment: I understood in the same way as you explained when reading these similar syntactic constructions: ἐκ πίστεως εἰς πίστιν (Rom. 1:17 BGT)  and ἐκ γῆς εἰς γῆν  (Sir. 41:10 BGT);  ἐξ οἰκίας εἰς οἰκίαν  (Sir. 29:24 BGT); ἐκ γενεᾶς εἰς γενεάν (Prov. 27:24 BGT); ἐκ δυνάμεως εἰς δύναμιν  (Ps. 83:8 BGT); ἐξ ἡμερῶν εἰς ἡμέρας;  ἐκ δυνάμεως εἰς δύναμιν (Ps. 83:8 BGT); ἐκ κακῶν εἰς κακα (Jer. 9:2 BGT); ἐξ ἀγγείου εἰς ἀγγεῖον (Jer. 31:11 BGT); ἐξ οἰκίας εἰς οἰκίαν (Lk. 10:7 BGT); ἐκ θανάτου εἰς θάνατον (2 Cor. 2:16 BGT); ἐκ ζωῆς εἰς ζωήν (2 Cor. 2:16 BGT)

Answer (score 0):

Aaron Nutt:

I'm not sure what you mean - precisely - by "transitional temporal meaning". I believe there can be no doubt that a transition of some kind is being conveyed. A "from-to" formulation of any set of nouns necessarily implies transition.

But when I read Romans 1:17, I immediately think of Psalm 84:7; 2 Corinthians 3:16-18; and 2 Corinthians 2:16. The idea of an increasing measure is the most obvious meaning in each case. In all of these passages, the Scripture seems to speak of growth and movement resulting in, respectively, more and more faith *[with an accompanying experiential awareness ("revelation") of the righteousness that results from this growing faith]*, and more and more strength, glory, spiritual death and spiritual life.

In the broader context of Romans *(thinking of Abraham as the father of those who believe)*, a growing faith is the kind of faith Paul has in mind. In Romans 4:21 and 22, Paul writes that Abraham "did not waver in unbelief but grew strong in faith". "Therefore", Paul states, "faith was credited to him as righteousness."

In short the temporal transition, "from faith to faith", seems to be one of increasing faith and an increasing experience of God's righteousness.

Answer (score 0):

There is temporal aspect to faith:

> *Now faith is the substance of things hoped for, the evidence of things not seen. (Hebrews 11:1 NKJV)*

Faith is the evidence of things not seen. Once the thing hoped for is realized, it is reality and no longer requires faith.

Consider the example of Abram:

> *Now the LORD had said to Abram: “Get out of your country, from your family and from your father’s house, to a land that I will show you...(Genesis 12:1 NKJV)*

Abram had not seen the land yet he had faith and left Haran. When the LORD showed him the land Abram no longer needed faith. Before seeing the land Abram could only rely on his hope; eventually he could use a map.

There were additional things the LORD told Abram:

> *I will make you a great nation; I will bless you and make your name great; and you shall be a blessing. I will bless those who bless you, and I will curse him who curses you; and in you all the families of the earth shall be blessed.”
>    (Genesis 12:2-3 NKJV)*

In those Abram still hoped. God’s work was and is progressive. As one part is accomplished and seen or experienced, reality replaces faith in that part.

The LORD worked in Abram’s life and God was revealed from faith to faith.

Answer (score 0):

Paul concludes the verse by citing Habakkuk 2:4 LXX. In other words, Paul is saying, "I'm just saying what Habakkuk 2:4 LXX said":

> [Rom 1:17 NKJV] (17) For in it the righteousness of God is revealed from faith to faith; **as it is written, "The just shall live by faith."**

I consider it reasonable that if one understands Habakkuk 2:4 LXX as Paul did, they will understand what Paul intended in Romans 1:17a. To that end I have been pursuing understanding this with the help of the scholars [at the Biblical Greek forum.](http://www.ibiblio.org/bgreek/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=5202&hilit=live%20by%20faith) I strongly urge all interested in this passage to read the discussion there.

It turns out that there are major concerns about the transmission of this text. [Was it even in the oldest versions of Habakkuk?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/45219/is-habakkuk-24-dss-an-interpolation-in-progress)

And whose faith is it? Quite the can of worms.

At the aforementioned forum I am seeking an understanding of the preposition "ek" which I would have thought would be a "dia". "Out of faith"? And then, "eis" - "into faith"?

I have come to understand Paul to be saying that justification can be understood as originating from faith in God's promises and results in faithfulness (obedience). And this life of faithfulness to God is God's righteousness. "The righteous are those who believe my promises and thus live righteously".

Jesus, Paul, James, Hebrews, etc. all see the paradigm of Habakkuk as a faith as resulting in faithfulness. It is not a one time belief event but a lifetime of faithfulness:

> [Heb 10:38 NKJV] (38) Now the just shall live by faith; **But if anyone draws back, My soul has no pleasure in him."**

So that is the righteousness of God. It is complete in effecting righteousness without Torah observance. It is accomplished to the end the same way it begins:

> NIV Galatians 3:3 Are you so foolish? After beginning by means of the Spirit, are you now trying to finish by means of the flesh?

Answer (score 0):

> **Romans 1:17 (NA28)** δικαιοσύνη γὰρ θεοῦ ἐν αὐτῷ ἀποκαλύπτεται **ἐκ πίστεως εἰς πίστιν** καθὼς γέγραπται ὁ δὲ δίκαιος ἐκ πίστεως ζήσεται.
>
> **(My translation)** For in it the righteousness of God is revealed **by faith unto faith,** just as it is written: But the righteous *man* shall live by faith.

We should allow St. Paul to explain his own meaning. He quotes a passage directly supporting his claim that God's righteousness is revealed in the gospel ἐκ πίστεως (by faith). Here, St. Paul seems to be quoting from the Hebrew rather than the Greek:

He quotes from Habakkuk 2:4:

> **(WLC)** הנה עפלה לא־ישרה נפשו בו וצדיק באמונתו יחיה׃
>
> **(My translation)** Behold the proud *man*: his soul is not right within him: but the righteous *man* shall live by his faith.

(The 'his' in 'his faith' is more of a Hebraism/peculiarity of Hebrew than a real difference in quotation, in my estimation, and is merely a tool for emphasis in contrasting the wicked and the righteous in the Hebrew.)

Here in the Hebrew, the meaning is clear: the righteous man shall live according to, by, and in his faith, thus leading to the uprightness of the soul, unlike the proud and unbelieving.

In another passage in the New Testament, however, the author of Hebrews quotes from the LXX tradition for this passage.

> **Hebrew 1:36-38 (ASV)** For ye have need of patience, that, having done the will of God, ye may receive the promise. For yet a little while, and he that shall come will come, and will not tarry. But **my** righteous one shall live by faith: **And if he shrink back, my soul hath no pleasure in him.**”

The bolded portions are features only of the LXX tradition. (In addition, the author of Hebrews freely swaps the clauses centered around the semicolon to flow better for his argument.)

So now we have two passages citing this verse and "by faith," whose meaning is thus clear: living **by faith** is in contrast to shrinking back, in contrast to being proud, in contrast to now having an upright state of the soul. It means living according to faith: being "doers of the word, and not hearers only" (Jas 1:22).

So what does the righteousness of God being revealed "by faith" mean? That living righteously, and thus reflecting God's righteousness, reveals God's righteousness to the world. And this is conducive to faith **("unto faith")** in others and in an increase in those already in possession of it.

Comment: I can't seem to locate it in the history here but at one point I believe I raised the question whether the phrase "shall live" means "shall be made alive" or "conduct one's affairs" and the answer came back that it means "shall be made alive". Can you please check on that because if I'm correct it gives a different interpretation from what you are presenting. Without looking I'm pretty certain that Paul was NOT hoping to suggest that "righteous conduct" was the means of either life or justification. For Paul, faith stands alone and those baptized by the spirit into Christ are "complete in him"

Comment: Righteous conduct wouldn't be the *means* here anyway (no more than the choice to accept Jesus is the 'means' of salvation), but definitional to true faith. Paul condemns that view of righteousness of man being BY MEANS OF his good deeds. Here he would be saying *you don't truly have the means* (faith) if you aren't conducting yourself righteously.Hence, "and if he [the righteous living by his faith] shall shrink back, my soul shall have no pleasure in him." Faith in God's eyes is only faith when you persevere in it and live according to that profession: "faith, if it hath not works, is dead."

Comment: Also, Galatians 3:12 is in a very similar context and usage of language, in fact it's the exact same subject spoken of here, and it says: "And the Law is not ἐκ [according to, based on, of] faith; on the contrary: He that does these things shall live by them." Clearly, this verb doesn't mean 'shall be made alive by God' but rather 'by means of the works he procures life before God'—and of course no one can, is Paul's argument. Hence faith and access to the mercy that comes only by grace and which is incompatible with the perfect keeping of the Law.

Comment: You wrote: "So what does the faith of God being revealed "by faith" mean? That living righteously, and thus reflecting God's righteousness, reveals God's righteousness to the world." This is tangential but the "revealing" is, as I understand it, that which is revealed by God - that faith stands alone apart from works. I don't think the idea that he means "is displayed".

Comment: You're certainly entitled to differ. Also, thanks for catching the typo. In my understanding, the wrath of God is made known to us in that God has left these godless men to wicked devices and perversities. Similarly, the righteousness of God is made known through his saints and what he does for them through faith in Him.

Comment: "Living righteously" appears to be your translation of ζάω which properly does not mean "conduct oneself" but rather "become alive" or "stay alive". As I said, this is a completely different viewpoint from your premise, that ζάω means to conduct oneself.

Comment: 'Living by' is already a Hebraism, meaning it is how you will sustain yourself (i.e. not be lost): 'he will keep himself alive, he will live, and be just, through and by faith, and not by his own keeping of the Law.' Clearly, staying 'alive' depends on not 'shrinking back,' which only confirms my view, and contradicts your view of faith (Rev 2:4-5).

Comment: Do you see "shrinking back" as anything other than abandoning faith? Are you suggesting that it is failing to receive "absolution" and the like? Or keeping Torah? Or just "being good enough"? I was careful to point out that faith *is* required by Paul's assertion. It begins at faith and ends with faith. It sounds to me that you want to add works of "righteous living".

Comment: It's exactly what Revelation 2:4-5; Mt 24:12-13; Heb 1:36, 38 etc. explicitly say.

Comment: All of those texts are Jewish texts and not Pauline. You might as well be quoting the Torah.

Comment: Well, that makes no sense: Paul is writing Jewish texts, and is a Jew. Alas, we once again run into the tangential comment section debate problem :/

Comment: Speaking loosely, Jesus did not come to set aside the law, Paul did. Revelation was placed last in the Protestant canon because of all the writings of Paul it was the least relevant. And "Hebrews" is actually "To the Hebrews" - not to you and I. But in the new humanity there is no Jew nor gentile (for any practical purpose). Understanding and respecting this distinction in dispensations shuts down the confusion of grace vs works that normally ensues when people confound the texts of the different dispensations.

Comment: There aren't two standards for one race, and one for another race for salvation. The whole New Testament is literally one big argument against that. God is no respecter of persons: Mt 3:9; Rom 11:20-23. Also, Revelation wasn't written by Paul, wasn't placed last by Protestants, since they didn't exist yet to 'place' anything; and it wasn't because it was irrelevant that it appears last. Your history is *way* off there. No letter of Paul was written to 'you and I,' but to the respective churches; and his arguments in Hebrews aren't specific to Jews anyway.. moot point.

Comment: Matthew 24 speaks of the destruction of Jerusalem and the temple and "the end of the age". Do you recognize that God dealt differently with Israel, at least until the end of the age in 70AD, than he did with the nations? And that the gentiles are not nor ever have been beholden to the law of Moses?

Comment: Of course God dealt differently with Israel than the other nations before the New Covenant. Literally no one denies that. The point is that the means of salvation can't be inconsistent between the two: if something makes one right before God, it does. It doesn't matter what color your skin is or what gender you are. The difference was that God spoke to one nation out of whom to bring the Saviour of the world. He gate them a holy code to live by, as opposed to living as the Gentiles. But as was pointed out in the NT, NO ONE can keep His moral law perfectly.

Comment: Actually the new covenant is only with the houses of Israel and Judah. Thus saith the LORD. And it was specifically made to deal with the infractions of Torah (by the Jews):  ESV To the Hebrews 9:15 "Therefore he is the mediator of a new covenant, so that those who are called may receive the promised eternal inheritance [ie: the land/kingdom], since a death has occurred that redeems **them from the transgressions committed under the first covenant**."

Comment: I'd love to continue but this is not the place.

Answer (score 0):

From faith to faith simply means from Judaism to Christianity; from the law to grace; from condemnation to salvation. It's a spiritual journey.

Answer (score 0):

The Apostle was being used by The Holy Ghost to share that God REVEALS HIS Righteousness unto us (mankind) from One Level of Faith to ANOTHER. AS we CONTINUE to walk WITH The Holy Ghost,(Who IS God),we are being CONFORMED to The IMAGE of Christ in our GROWTH and in our walk. This is speaking of a CONTINUOUS walk,even during our fallings,IF we are REALLY predestined by The Holy Ghost to go with Him.If we are a part of the elect mentioned in Ephesians 1:5-14,then OUR WALK experiences GROWTH from ONE Level of Faith to ANOTHER...(in Jesus' Name,Amen)...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Paul is saying that righteousness is revealed in saving people by faith. They go from being unrighteous, when they do not have faith, to being made righteous BY their faith.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/45966)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

OP's  question, What does Paul mean by from faith to faith"

> For in it God's righteousness is revealed out of faith for faith, according at is written:  Now the just by faith shall live. Rom. 1:17 Concordant literal

This word study (below)is helpful in understanding that God's righteousness is being revealed out of the source of God, unto the object of either Jew or Gentile for power to salvation by simply believing  God's good news.

> 1537 ek (a preposition, written eks before a vowel) – properly, "out from and to" (the outcome); out from within. 1537 /ek ("out of") is one of the most under-translated (and therefore mis-translated) Greek propositions – often being confined to the meaning "by." 1537 (ek) has a two-layered meaning ("out from and to") which makes it out-come oriented (out of the depths of the source and extending to its impact on the object).

It is God's righteousness that is being revealed through the faith OF  Christ.  He alone as the son of man, had  faith in God by His perfect obedience to God's will to go to the cross.  This is the only true Faith that brings salvation and righteousness and makes men just.  It's also the law being fulfilled by "love the Lord thy God with all thy heart with all thy soul and with all thy mind and thy neighbor as thyself.  His love was first to God the Father  and also showed His and the Fathers love for men by laying  down  His life on their behalf when they were yet sinners.

This is God's own  righteousness that is freely given to one who believes God.

> The righteousness of God is through the faith of Jesus Christ to all, and upon all those believing, -- for there is no difference, Romans 3:22

Christ being in union with man, died with man as he tasted death for all men.  Jesus Christ dying, being buried and being raised into new life is the new creation that has no more sin inside it.

> 1519 eis (a preposition) – properly, into (unto) – literally, "motion into which" implying penetration ("unto," "union") to a particular purpose or result.

It is from Christ's faith in God and our faith in Christ and God because of what they did together.  God was in Christ reconciling the world unto himself.

This is what makes Jesus Christ the perfect mediator between God and man, as He represents both.  Being in Union with God and in Union with man.

This evangel that Paul is preaching, is revealing how God imparts His own righteousness to those who accept what He has done through Christ.  It was God's will  and Christ followed in perfect faith by His obedience to the death of the cross.

Those who rely and put their faith in Christ's work alone are living because they too are counted as just, Not just forgiven but justified.  In Christ they are as perfect as Jesus Christ.  This is God's righteousness being revealed out of faith for faith.  Basically we are putting our faith in Christ's faith by what He did through the cross.  He completed the work the Father had given him to do.  The work was completed.
.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely temporal deictic in meaning; but doesn't mean from law to faith, since law is not like faith, it is contrasted by Paul in defense of the new covenant. It is similar to John 1:16 *grace upon grace* to show the abundance and increasing grace of God.

John Gill,

> from faith to faith; that is, as say some, from the faith of God to the faith of men; from the faith of preachers to the faith of hearers; **from the faith of the Old to the faith of the New** Testament saints; or rather from one degree of faith to another; for faith, as it grows and increases, has clearer sights of this righteousness, as held forth in the Gospel. For the proof of this, a passage of Scripture is cited

The scripture cited (Hab) specifies the deictic reference explaining the meaning as transitional from faith of the old times to the faith of new, the covenant of Christ. All such construct are deictic expressing *from one to another*; from then to now.

*Deictic* is a term used in linguistics to refer to words and phrases that require contextual information to be fully understood. Deictic words are those whose semantic meaning is fixed but whose denoted meaning varies depending on time, place, or person. Examples of deictic words include pronouns such as "we", "you", and "they", as well as temporal adverbs such as "now" and "then". Deixis is closely related to [anaphora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endophora) and can be used metaphorically rather than physically in some contexts.

Roberto posted similar syntactical references in the comments:

> ἐκ πίστεως εἰς πίστιν (Rom. 1:17 BGT) and ἐκ γῆς εἰς γῆν (Sir. 41:10 BGT); ἐξ οἰκίας εἰς οἰκίαν (Sir. 29:24 BGT); ἐκ γενεᾶς εἰς γενεάν (Prov. 27:24 BGT); ἐκ δυνάμεως εἰς δύναμιν (Ps. 83:8 BGT); ἐξ ἡμερῶν εἰς ἡμέρας; ἐκ δυνάμεως εἰς δύναμιν (Ps. 83:8 BGT); ἐκ κακῶν εἰς κακα (Jer. 9:2 BGT); ἐξ ἀγγείου εἰς ἀγγεῖον (Jer. 31:11 BGT); ἐξ οἰκίας εἰς οἰκίαν (Lk. 10:7 BGT); ἐκ θανάτου εἰς θάνατον (2 Cor. 2:16 BGT); ἐκ ζωῆς εἰς ζωήν (2 Cor. 2:16 BGT)

Answer (score -1):

Nothing beats reading and understanding the original koine Greek.

> δικαιοσυνη γαρ θεου εν αυτω αποκαλυπτεται εκ πιστεως εις πιστιν

- collective-rightness of god is enclosed/revealed out-of belief into belief.

[δικαιοσυνη] is an interesting word. Doing right together. This word and its various declensions, translated as "righteousness" or "justice", used throughout Christian scriptures, suggest that the concept of "personal salvation" is a modern evangelical invention. If so, for a bible-fundamentalist, there is no such thing as "personal salvation".

The derivation of apocalypse [αποκαλυψις] is also interesting. How does a word from its components would mean "by covering", get to become the meaning "reveal"? Perhaps, the word actually originally meant "broadcast" or mass-cast.

[εκ πιστεως εις πιστιν] out of belief into belief. Would that phrase need further "revelation"? From bounds to bounds. Gradually, from white belt graduate into yellow belt. From primary school 1, into primary 2, into middle school, into junior, into senior.

I am not much of a Christianity "theologist", but the language suggests

> The collective-rightness of god is mass-proffered graduating from levels of belief into levels of belief.

The Hebrew word [אמונה] EMUNaH is from the root word [אמן] AMN, which connotes agreement. [אמונה] EMUNaH means trust and confidence.

There is no such thing as "personal salvation" as far as the Bible, whether Christian or Jewish sections, is concerned. It takes a village to work together to achieve salvation, graduating from levels to levels of communal trust and confidence.

For one is made collectively right not by effort alone, but by alignment with the communal agreement in trust and confidence.

Comment: "There is no such thing as 'personal salvation' as far as the Bible... is concerned." That's your opinion - fair enough. I do get what you're trying to say, but there are more than a few passages which disagree with you: Acts 22:16 Paul washes away 'his' sins; 1 Cor 3:15 The man who builds poorly is 'saved', but only barely; 1 Cor 5:5 Expel an individual so that he may be 'saved'. Acts 8:26-40 An individual Ethiopian is saved. Yes the communal aspect is the primary one, but there is definitely an individual aspect in the NT.

Comment: @Blessed Geek *απο* is a pre**position** used to indicate a starting point, which is why it is often translated "from". So, according to the components, αποκαλυψις literally means "from [a place of] cover", which is why you end up with "reveal".